# Inconsistent number of publications retrieved from Scopus using pybliometrics

Tags: pybliometrics

I tried using pybliometrics to get info from Scopus on publications from my institution, but got different results from the AffiliationSearch and the AffiliationRetrieval.

I got the ID and other info with AffiliationSearch, including the number of documents:

`[Affiliation(eid='10-s2.0-60092193', name='Instituto de Biología Molecular y Celular de Rosario', variant='Instituto De Biología Molecular Y Celular De Rosario', documents=1171, city='Rosario', country='Argentina', parent='0')]`

Now, when I retrieve the affiliation info with AffiliationRetrieval, the number of documents appears to drop substantially from 1171 to 221

`Instituto de Biología Molecular y Celular de Rosario in Rosario in Argentina, has 116 associated author(s) and 221 associated document(s) as of 2023-02-16`

When I get to the Scopus Affiliation Link, obtained from the same AffiliationRetrieval object, the page informs again 1171 documents

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mysterious. All APIs, incl. Scopus Search API, return the number 1171. Only Affiliation Retrieval API returns a different number.

I tried with my own institution (60105007). The number obtained from Affiliation Retrieval API differs from the other APIs, but it is a little higher.

This is in any case not a problem with your code or with `pybliometrics`. Maybe consult Sopus directly? Could be a mistake in the Affiliation Retrieval API.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I will ask Scopus, I'll let you know what they tell me. in any case, as you say, I can get the full document list with ScopusSearch.